# mount -t cifs: "Operation not supported", but can connect via smbclient

Tags: samba, cifs, smb

After sysadmin replaced the NAS, I can no longer mount the network share with

```
sudo mount -t cifs //netgear.local/public /media/mountY -o uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,username="adam",password="password"
```

Both NAS are linux-based, one with Samba 3.5.15 (the old one) and the other with Samba 3.5.16 (the new one) (information obtained from smbclient)

I can, however, log in and use the share with the help of `smbclient`, like this:

```
smbclient  //NETGEARV2/public -U adam
```

What can I do? There is no `smbmount` on Linux Mint (nor on Ubuntu) anymore.

When I check `dmesg` I get this info:

```
CIFS VFS: Send error in QFSUnixInfo = -95
CIFS VFS: cifs_read_super: get root inode failed
```

Comment: In Ubuntu you have to install smbfs package.

Comment: If the NAS are Linux based, do you need to access via CIFS? If they are exported with NFS as well, you should just use NFS instead.

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu as I said, there is no smbfs on recent Ubuntu. It says it is depreciated, and `sudo apt-get install smbfs` yelds `E: Package 'smbfs' has no installation candidate`. Package `cifs-utils` replace it, which boils down to `mount -t cifs`.

Comment: Check `dmesg`, there should be further details about what went wrong from the kernel.

Comment: related question, in the context of ACL (`cifsacl`): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403509/how-to-enable-unix-file-permissions-on-samba-share-with-smb-2-0

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After seeing the dmseg and Googling, I found the solution:

One has to add the `sec=ntlm` option. The problem (feature?) is introduced in recent kernels (I use 3.8.4). I just didn't realize that the problem is kernel-related. So the correct way of mounting is:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //netgear.local/public /media/mountY -o uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,username="adam",password="password",sec=ntlm
```

Comment: b.t.w. - it also works if you add `sec=ntlm` using `mount.cifs`. ( `sudo mount.cifs '\\server\share' '/mnt/share' -o domain=DOMAIN,username=USERNAME,sec=ntlm`

Answer (score 51):

At work I encountered a similar problem. `moun -t cifs` just stopped working. Following [mounting a CIFS/SMB resource](https://plus.google.com/+ThorstenLeemhuis/posts/gnGwqw6EGNd) and looking at the output of `demsg`, I found that adding the option `vers=1.0` did the trick. My command looks like

> mount -t cifs //server/folder ./mountpoint -o user=USER,domain=DOMAIN,vers=1.0

Comment: `vers=2.0` can be a solution as well.

Comment: `vers=2.0` worked for me. No luck with `sec=ntlm`

Comment: The root cause seems to shift over time: In 2013, most people needed `sec=ntlm`, then it was mostly a missing `vers=1.0`, now we see first occurrences of `vers=2.0`.  :-)

Comment: `vers=3.0` worked for me. This could be a solution for someone else I hope.