# Can't mount SMB share Mint

Tags: windows, mount, smb

This has been driving me nuts for a while I am trying to mount a SMB share on a windows 2012 server. The share is there but every time that I try to mount it I get the following error

```
james-virtual-machine james # mount -t cifs //DOLA0056-WS/wssmbshare /samba/wssmbshare -o username=James
Password for James@//**DOLA0056-WS**/wssmbshare: 
**mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)**

james-virtual-machine james # mount -t cifs //172.16.90.79/wssmbshare /samba/wssmbshare -o username=James
Password for James@//**172.16.90.79**/wssmbshare: 
**mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)**
```

the share link is \DOLA0056-WS\wssmbshare

the domain is nssDOLA0056.cst8242.com

the user James has been given full control

These are the contents of the /etc/samba/smb.conf file

```
[global]
client man protocol = SMB2
#client ntlmv2 auth = yes 
#client use spnego principal = no
#send spnego pricipal = no 
workgroup = nssdola0056.cst8242.com
security = domain
netbios name = DOLA0056-LC
#server = access
#server string =
name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
preferred master = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

this is the contents of the resolv.conf file 
nameserver 172.16.90.79
search nssDOLA0056.cst8242.com

DNS appears to be working,

james-virtual-machine james # nslookup 172.16.90.79
Server:     172.16.90.79
Address:    172.16.90.79#53

79.90.16.172.in-addr.arpa   name = ns.nssdola0056.cst8242.com.
79.90.16.172.in-addr.arpa   name = dola0056-ws.nssdola0056.cst8242.com.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using mint Cinnamon.

Comment: Its hilarious that askubuntu bails on Mint questions.. ITS THE SAME THING.. gah. Anyway, this works on my mint: ```sudo mount -t cifs //fileserver/folder /path/test -o,username=USERNAME```, Are you getting anything in the servers /var/log/samba folder?

Comment: mount -t cifs //dola0056-ws/wssmbshare /samba/wssmbshare/ -o,username=james
Password for james@//dola0056-ws/wssmbshare: 
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) the command that you suggested above results in the same host is down error. As for a log on the Windows server (server 2012), I have to be honest i don't exactly know where to look.

Comment: -1, abandoned. This similar Q might help searchers who land here though (how to force SMB2/3): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144522/mounting-cifs-operation-not-supported