# Why am I getting mount error Operation not supported?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab

VM running Ubnutu v18.04:

In /etc/fstab I have the following (pw elided):

```
//216TN53/UbuntuShare /mnt/data cifs username=kafkaetl,password=*******,uid=nobody,iocharset=utf8,noperm 0 0
```

mount -av is returning

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=172.21.208.1,unc=\\216TN53\UbuntuShare,iocharset=utf8,noperm,uid=65534,user=kafkaetl,pass=********
mount error(95): Operation not supported
```

I'm unable to see my error -there's obviously a problem, but I don't see it.
My thanks to anyone that does see it!

Answer (score 0):

[Mounting cifs: "Operation not supported"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144522/mounting-cifs-operation-not-supported) seems like same issue, and based on top answer, need to specify SMB version, which is missing in options in the question here.